# laravel 5.4 custom error message for MIME not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, custom-validators

Dearest,

I want to make a custom error message for uploaded image,

here's my controller code :

```
protected function validator($data = [], $validateContent = []){
    $messages = [
        'imgUserAvatar:mimes' => 'File Type must be in jpeg,jpg,png'
    ];

    return Validator::make($data, $validateContent, $messages);
}
$validateContent = [
            'imgUserAvatar'     => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:2000',
            'textUserEmail'     => 'required|unique:admin_user,user_email|max:50',
            'textFirstName'     => 'required|max:50',
            'textLastName'      => 'max:50',
            'textPwd'           => 'required|min:6|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
            'textPwdConfrim'    => 'required|same:textPwd'
        ];

        $validation = $this->validator($request->all(), $validateContent);
```

but this custom message do not want to show up, the default message shown [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCp46.png)

is there something i mistakenly code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `dot` between field and rule, so you should use:

```
$messages = [
    'imgUserAvatar.mimes' => 'File Type must be in jpeg,jpg,png'
];
```

instead of

```
$messages = [
    'imgUserAvatar:mimes' => 'File Type must be in jpeg,jpg,png'
];
```