# customize error message for mimes not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I can not customize the error message for mimes

I try the solution given here [laravel 5.4 custom error message for MIME not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803218/laravel-5-4-custom-error-message-for-mime-not-working) but without success

Request :

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules =  [
        'album'=> 'required',
        'add_image.*' => 'image|mimes:png|max:2000',
    ];
    return $rules;
}
public function messages()
{
    $messages = [
        'album.required' => 'Album is required',
        'add_image.mimes' => "Image isn't png",
    ];

    return $messages;
}
```

Form view :

```
<form class="addImage" method="post" action="{{route('addImage.form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <select name="album">
         <option value="">-----</option>
         @foreach($albums as $album)
             <option value="{{$album}}">{{$album}}</option>
         @endforeach

    </select>
    <input  multiple="multiple" name="add_image[]" type="file" />
    <button class="buttonADM" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You are validating an array, so try this instead:

```
'add_image.*.mimes' => "Image isn't png",
```

I used your form on my project, and tried this:

```
$valid  = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
    'add_image.*' => 'image|mimes:png'
], [
    'add_image.*.mimes' => 'Image isnt png'
]);

dd($valid->errors());
// output
{
    "add_image.0": [
    "Image isnt png"
  ],
    "add_image.1": [
    "Image isnt png"
  ],
    "add_image.2": [
    "Image isnt png"
  ]
}
```

and I got the custom message. So please check your error bag if it contains the correct messages, and make sure that you print it okay.

Comment: Can you please show me the code of the input field that you are trying to validate?

Comment: I double checked now on one of my projects, and you can see the output above.

Answer (score 0):

i have not same result

Controller

```
public function addImage(/*addImageRequest $request*/){

    if(session('user')['isA'] == 1){
        $valid  = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'add_image.*' => 'image|mimes:png'
        ], [
            'add_image.*.mimes' => 'Image isnt png'
        ]);
       dd($valid->errors());
    }
}
```

Return :

```
MessageBag {#224 ▼
    #messages: array:1 [▼
        "add_image.0" => array:1 [▼
             0 => "The add_image.0 failed to upload."
        ]
    ]
    #format: ":message"
}
```

Comment: Failed to upload is completely different message. What file type are you trying to upload? Is the type of the file an image at least, to pass the first rule, before the mime type?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry ! 
the file I am trying to download is in uppercase font .JPG the file is not considered an image with a .jpg image I get the error.

sorry for the loss of time ... and thanks for your help !

Comment: You can accept my answer as the correct one to help others my friend. Happy coding.